# Event handler PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx call giving 503 error

Tags: powershell-extensions, gulp

I have a local Sitecore instance with name sc90.local and I am trying to publish files on local instance using gulp.

Response error:

```
Upload failed: styles.css
Status code:503
URL: POST http://sc90.local//sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx?user=sitecore%5Cadmin&#038;password=b&#038;script=Foundation%5CXA%20Extensions%5CREACT%5CREACT/styles&#038;sc_database=master&#038;apiVersion=media&#038;scriptDb=master
Category: Uncategorized URLs
Reason: UNKNOWN
Notification: DNS_FAIL
```

It is saying DNS Fail - but i have verified my local sitecore instance and it is working fine. I also checked the host file for (sc90.local) website and it is pointing to local system (127.0.0.1)
My system is behind the proxy so I set the proxy values on command prompt.

the file is also located in the system:

[image]

on printing the response body on command prompt I got some html which seems like my company standard response page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Notification: DNS Failure</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo"><img src="http://proxycfg.int.COMP.ca/COMP-logo.jpg" border="0"></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="shadow">
<h1>This Page Cannot Be Displayed</h1>
<p>
The host name resolution (DNS lookup) for this host name
(&nbsp;sc90.local&nbsp;) has failed. The Internet address may be misspelled or obsolete,
the host (&nbsp;sc90.local&nbsp;) may be temporarily unavailable,
or the DNS server may be unresponsive.
</p>
<p>
Please check the spelling of the Internet address entered.
If it is correct, try this request later.
</p>
<p><b> To Learn more about the COMP Internet Access Policy:   <a href="http://its.COMP/iso/websense.htm">COMP Internet Access Policy</a> </b></p>
<p>
If you have questions, please contact
Service Desk Ext. 1234
and provide the codes shown below.
</p>
</div>
<div class="details"><p>
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 09:34:59 EST<br />
Username: INTCOMPCA\username@INTCOMPCA<br />
Source IP: [my IP]<br />
URL: POST http://sc90.local//sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx?user=sitecore%5Cadmin&#038;password=b&#038;script=Foundation%5CXA%20Extensions%5CREACT%5CREACT/scripts&#038;sc_database=master&#038;apiVersion=media&#038;scriptDb=master<br />
Category: Uncategorized URLs<br />
Reason: UNKNOWN<br />
Notification: DNS_FAIL
</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the complete stack trace of the error from cmd prompt

Comment: @AbhayDhar : Added the response body in the question. There is a request structure as : ```` let headerAuth={'Authorization' : syncArgv.basicAuth};
  let url = [
    options.server,
    options.uploadScriptPath,
    '?user=',
    options.user,
    '&password=',
    options.password,
    '&script=',
    options.mediaLibPath,
    '/',
    relativePath,
    '&sc_database=master&apiVersion=media&scriptDb=master'
  ].join(''); ''''

Comment: and you are running gulp on the same machine where sitecore is installed ?

Comment: yes, I am running everything on single local machine.

Comment: strange thing is, when I try to access the same url from browser i get : "HTTP Error 403.0 - The request could not be completed because the service is disabled.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page." system error page. URL is : http://sc90.local//sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx?user=sitecore%5Cadmin&#038;password=b&#038;script=Foundation%5CXA%20Extensions%5CREACT%5CREACT/styles&#038;sc_database=master&#038;apiVersion=media&#038;scriptDb=master

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the IIS settings, Sitecore installation gave only https binding on website and not the http binding and the url in the question is trying to access the file on http.